# OleDbCommand throw exception on valid command text

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb

I have OleDbConnection to connect to access database. But when I execute a query, OleDbCommand throw exception saying that command is invalid. I am perfectly sure that command is valid.

```
 string ret = "";

string command = "UPDATE tblUser set username = ?, password = ? where ID = 1";
dbConn.Open();

using (var dbCommand = dbConn.CreateCommand())
{
    dbCommand.Connection = dbConn;
    dbCommand.CommandText = command;
    dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", username);
    dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", password);

    int temp = dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (temp > 0)
        ret = "sukses";
    dbConn.Close();                
}
return ret;
```

However when code above is executed, it throw exception saying `Syntax error in UPDATE statement.` at `dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`. How to deal with this problem?

Comment: Perhaps username and password are reserved words? Also it shouldn't be necessary to add parameters with the name ? because OleDbParameters are positional, not named. In b4 all the code examples using named parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to escape `PASSWORD` with brackets since it is a reserved keyword,

```
UPDATE tblUser set username = ?, [password] = ? where ID = 1
```

- [MS Access Reserved Keywords](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx)